# How would I find the count of groups of 0s in multiple binary data frames in a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, r-raster, r-package

I am trying to output the number of groups on 0s in multiple data frames in a list. I believe the package I need to do this is the raster R package. Here is my attempt...

```
set.seed(12345)
output_1 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)
df_output_1 <- data.frame(output_1)

set.seed(99999)
output_2 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)
df_output_2 <- data.frame(output_2)

output_list <- list(df_output_2, df_output_2)

install.packages("raster")
library(raster)

lapply(output_list, function (onedf) {
  Rastermat <- raster(onedf)
  Clumps <- as.matrix(clump(Rastermat, directions = 8))

  #turning the clumps into a list
  tot <- max(Clumps, na.rm=TRUE)
  res <- vector("list", tot)
  for (i in 1:tot){
    res[i] <- list(which(Clumps == i, arr.ind = TRUE))
  }
  res
})
```

But I get the following error:

> Error in .local(x, ...) : list has no "x"
>
> 6. stop("list has no \"x\"")
> 7. .local(x, ...)
> 8. raster(onedf)
> 9. raster(onedf)
> 10. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
>
> 1.lapply(df_list, function(onedf) {
>
> Rastermat <- raster(onedf)
>
> Clumps <- as.matrix(clump(Rastermat, directions = 8))
>
> tot <- max(Clumps, na.rm = TRUE) ...

Can someone please help me? I am really stuck on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is that you need to use matrices instead of data.frames.

This should work:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(12345)
output_1 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)
set.seed(99999)
output_2 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)

output_list <- list(output_2, output_2)

lapply(output_list, function (onedf) {
  Rastermat <- raster(onedf)
  Clumps <- as.matrix(clump(Rastermat, directions = 8))
  tot <- max(Clumps, na.rm=TRUE)
  res <- vector("list", tot)
  for (i in 1:tot){
    res[i] <- list(which(Clumps == i, arr.ind = TRUE))
  }
  res
})
```

EDIT to answer your follow-up questions:

Provided **your input are data.frames containing 0s and 1s** and you want to **count the number of clumps of 0s** you could have following code to return a list of the number of clumps in each data.frame:

```
sapply(list_of_dfs, function(df) {
  rm <- raster(as.matrix(df)-1) # -1 because the clump function counts non-zero values
  rc <- clump(rm, directions = 8, gaps = F) # gaps = F to prevent having missing numbers in the chunk numbers
  rc@data@max # return the highest chunk number
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this @jkd! Would I need to convert my whole list of data frames to matrices first and then apply it to that function? To convert each data frame would I just use `data.matrix(output_list)` for example? Instead of displaying the position of each clump with res can I output the count of clumps for each?

Comment: Also @jkd! Does clumps not get the groups of 1s rather than 0s? :)

Comment: In your example the data you are generating is already in a matrix so no need to convert anything. If your actual data is in a `data.frame` then you could either change the function to perform the conversion itself (e.g. replace `Rastermat <- raster(onedf)` by `Rastermat <- raster(as.matrix(onedf))`) or perform the conversion of all data.frames in the list with `lapply(output_list, as.matrix)`.

Comment: I edited my answer to answer your other questions. Please consider marking the question as solved by ticking the checkmark left of my answer if this solved your problem

Comment: Great @jkd thanks! So does the addition of `-1` in the raster function target only the 0s or does this invert the raster in some way so it counts the 0s instead? Also does `rc@data@max` return the sum/count of all groups of 0 in each data frame? Could you explain this more if possible :)

Comment: @Jordan the `-1` substract one to every element of the matrix. So as I said it only works when you are working with ones and zeros only. But you can experiment with this yourself in an R console or read about it here: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/matrix

Comment: `rc@data@max` is returned for every element of the list of data frames, so the result will be a list. But just try it out. In programming you need to experiment a lot by yourself to master the language. Asking a lot of questions often seems easier but in the end this is not how you learn